# Scrolling to a WebElement and clicking on it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to automation and am practicing on the flipkart website.
On the page:

http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=clp_mobiles_CategoryLinksModule_0-2_catergorylinks_11_ViewAll

... when I try to click an element that is not in view of the page by scrolling to it, I get the exception: `Element is not clickable`

Below is the code:

```
WebElement mobile = driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//a[@title='Apple iPhone 6S (Silver, 128 GB) ']"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", mobile);
mobile.click();
```

I *believe* this issue is occurring because of the header available in flipkart: even though the window is getting scrolled to that particular element, the header is covering the element so it's not possible to click on it.

Can anyone help resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

1. Case where you want to click on a element that is not in view of the page (without scrolling) try below

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.get(
           "http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=clp_mobiles_CategoryLinksModule_0-2_catergorylinks_11_ViewAll");
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   // Take everything on the page in list first .
   List<WebElement> completecalContent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='fk-display-block']"));
   System.out.println(completecalContent.size());
   // printing all elements
   for (int i = 0; i < completecalContent.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println("Print complete Content : " + completecalContent.get(i).getText());
       if (completecalContent.get(i).getText().equals("Apple iPhone 5S (Space Grey, 16 GB)")) {
           // move to a specific element
           ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",
                   completecalContent.get(completecalContent.size() - 1));
           // move slightly up as blue header comes in the picture
           ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-100)");
           // then click on the element
           completecalContent.get(i).click();
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Case where you  want to scroll then in that case update above code with these lines.

A. if you want to scroll to the bottom of the page then

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

B. if u want to scroll to  a specific element then try this

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to element"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

C. if you want to scroll on the basis of coordinates then try this

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
```

Comment: Hi ranish, In the URL that i have provided, if we scroll to any webelement by using the code that you have provided, it will scroll to that element in such a way that the element will get covered in the blue header and it won't receive the click. Could you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: in my code and on my machine i am able to click on Apple iPhone 5S (Space Grey, 16 GB) // plz look in the if statement plz tell me which browser you are working

Comment: Iam using firefox browser. what if the element is not available in the first 20 elements.

Comment: then plz use any 3 of the options that i have provided in case 2 .let me check one more time blue header issue

Comment: In the above 3 options, scrolling to a fixed position is working..i want to scroll to dynamically to a web element and this is where the blue header comes into picture.

Comment: HI i have gone through once again you are right when u move to a specific element blue header comes in to picture so my idea is just before clicking the element do a slight up scroll it will make the element visible and then click also check the updated code for the same. hope now it solves your query

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scrolling up to web element you can try scrolling to little bit down in page like

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)"); //x value '250' can be altered
```

Else you can try scrolling to element which is good enough above to required element. It means in code you tried instead of taking required webelement just scroll upto web element above the required so that the header does not cover required element.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Hi Murali, what if the position of the element changes, we need to change the code right. I want to scroll to the element dynamically and click it.

Comment: Then you can get the position of your web element in selenium. Just Google it you will get the code. Once got the position say 200 then try some thing like 200-50 in above code so that we can get out if this issue

Comment: Hi Murali, i got the element coordinates by using getLocation(), but how to scroll to that coordinates as the coordinates should be given in the form of string. i want to give the coordinate variables in the javascript, how do we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are not certain about the element's position on the page, you can find the `co-ordinates` at run time and then execute your text.

You can get elements co-ordinate by using [Point](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Point.html)

```
Point point = element.getLocation();
int xcord = point.getX();  
int ycord = point.getY();
```

You can also get the dimensions of a webelement like its `Height` and `Width` using [Dimension](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Dimension.html)

Once you have the `x` and `y` co-ordinates and you have its dimensions. You can write your code to scroll till that particular co-ordinates on the page.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Paras, i got the element coordinates by using getLocation(), but how to scroll to that coordinates as the coordinates should be given in the form of string. i want to give the coordinate variables in the javascript, how do we do this?